# Chainsaw Muffler Gasket and Cooling Plate

Tags: muffler, chainsaw

I am trying to figure out how the muffler is supposed to be attached to my ms391 Stihl. Originally when I went to the dealership they said I needed a both a gasket and a cooling plate, but I could not figure out which way they went on. I found this diagram, but it sort of looks like it is one or the other. But even if that is true, other than taking the saw apart to compare the shape of the engine to the diagrams I still do not know how to proceed. The Saw just says MODEL:MS391 on guard.

Also as sort of an aside, the diagram shows a sealant bottle, but does not explain where it is used. Would that be with the gasket or some other part?

[image]

Comment: It looks to me as though either 25 or 16 could be the muffler, while 15 is a gasket and 24 is the cooling plate? If so, I'd say you need one or the other and not both ... this is dependent upon what it came with originally.

Answer (score 3):

I was eventually able to find a complete [MS391 service manual](https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf6/127/12673/1267226-stihl/ms_311.pdf?f43db7de8ba3b01b0d06e5e0b73ed14f), and it shows it just needing the gasket.